# Cron tab to run a java file

Tags: scripting, cron, java

I'm having issues getting a cron tab to run a java file every 5 minutes.

I have tried to create an executable script to see if that is what's needed:

My script and java file are both stored in `/usr/local/bin` and this is what I have in my crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/java-crontab.sh
```

This is what I have in my script

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME=usr/java/jdk1.6.0_40
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
java -jar /usr/local/bin/javatest.jar
```

---

Sorry update - my **JAVA_HOME** file is not stored in **usr/java** but in **usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre-headless**. However when I enter that path in the executable script file I don't have permission to do so.

Brand new to creating VM's so apologies for my utter confusion here!

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @hannah-s check the mailbox of the user that owns the crontab for error log emails,

Comment: Do you think you have to define JAVA_HOME each time you run a java app? You don't have to. Just use the absolute path to java:
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre-headless/java -jar ...

Comment: Ahhh i didn't know - it still isn't working I'm afraid unless i still have a typo, iv changed the script file to: #!/bin/bash export PATH=/usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre-headless:$PATH java -jar /usr/local/bin/javatest.jar but it isn't running :(

Answer (score 2):

your `java-crontab.sh` has a typo. `JAVA_HOME` should be an absolute path.

Simplifying, you could go with

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_40:$PATH
java -jar /usr/local/bin/javatest.jar
```

Comment: I've just realised that JAVA_HOME is set in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun. If I give rwx permissions and place that in my script should that theoretically work?

Comment: In theory. Don't forget to replace `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_40` with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`. Try running the script manually before configuring your crontab. If it fails, tell us what's going on, ...

Comment: Hello, so I ran the script using the bash command and I got an error saying 'exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.inovocationtargetexception etc etc

Comment: without the full trace and some visual on your sources, there's no way of telling what happened. Regardless, my first guess would be you're running an old version of Java: are you sure this jar is supposed to work with 1.6?

Comment: The sys log file just says 'NO MTA installed, discarding output' I did install postfix but the crontab still was not running the jar file so I returned to my earlier snapshot which was before I installed postfix. I also created a new logfile in hope the crontab would report the errors into that but the logfile remained blank

Comment: the problem is definitely not with your crontab, and probably not related to postfix either: obviously, you can't run this jar. Ask its author for support, he's the one that would understand whatever your trace is showing. AFAIU, the exception you're telling about isn't much helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception).